# Разархивирование zip файла в android

Tags: java, android, zip

Нужно программно разархивировать zip файл. Знаю про либу zip4j, но как я понял, получать прогресс из этой задачи не получится.

`AsyncTask`? Может быть в нем запускать разархивацию и сравнивать размеры файлов? Не вариант, так как степень сжатия неизвестна.

Да и вообще мне кажется все проще. Никто с этим не сталкивался?

Comment: Возможно Вам поможет [этот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947381/progress-bar-with-unzipping-of-file) вопрос и ответ на него.  А вообще можно найти очень много информации по запросу `android unzip with progressbar`. Я бы набросал небольшой пример, да сейчас компьютера под рукой нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция разархивирования:

```
public class Decompress { 
  private String zipFile; 
  private String location; 

  public Decompress(String zipFile, String location) { 
    this.zipFile = zipFile; 
    this.location = location; 

    dirChecker(""); 
  } 

  public void unzip() { 
    try  { 
      FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile); 
      ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
      ZipEntry ze = null; 
      while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) { 
        Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName()); 

        if(ze.isDirectory()) { 
          dirChecker(ze.getName()); 
        } else { 
          FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(location + ze.getName()); 
          for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) { 
            fout.write(c); 
          } 

          zin.closeEntry(); 
          fout.close(); 
        } 

      } 
      zin.close(); 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
      Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e); 
    } 

  } 

  private void dirChecker(String dir) { 
    File f = new File(location + dir); 

    if(!f.isDirectory()) { 
      f.mkdirs(); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Пример работы:

```
String zipFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/files.zip"; 
String unzipLocation = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/unzipped/"; 

Decompress d = new Decompress(zipFile, unzipLocation); 
d.unzip();
```

Comment: @post_zeew скинул пример с прогрессом