# Иероглифы вместо букв

Tags: java, файлы, кодировка, исключения, scanner

При попытке считать из `csv`-файла в `zip`-архиве с помощью `Scanner` выводятся иероглифы. Если без указания кодировки, то в основном это ромбики со знаком вопроса внутри.

Если указать кодировку `unicode`: `new Scanner(path, "Unicode");`, то получаю китайские иероглифы.
Использовать надо именно Scanner.

Так же выскакивает либо `FileSystemException`, либо `TranslateToIOException` и `retrowAsIoException`, либо какой-нибудь другой.

Вот мой код:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;
 
public class JavaFileScanner {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       
        String fileName = "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Jvdroid/single-files/_данные_Сбер_Java_20210407090226.zip";
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path);
         
        
        scanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("Строка: " + scanner.next());
        }
        scanner.close();
        
        scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get("/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Jvdroid/single-files/_данные_Сбер_Java_20210407090226.zip/city_ru.csv"));
        scanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            
            Employee emp = parseCSVLine(scanner.next());
            System.out.println(emp.toString());
        }
        scanner.close();
         
        
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Вводим первое слово: " + scanner.next());
    }
     
    private static Employee parseCSVLine(String line) {
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
         scanner.useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");
         String name = scanner.next();
         int age = scanner.nextInt();
         String gender = scanner.next();
         JavaFileScanner jfs = new JavaFileScanner();
         return jfs.new Employee(name, age, gender);
    }
 
    public class Employee{
        private String name;
        private int age;
        private String gender;
         
        public Employee(String n, int a, String gen){
            this.name = n;
            this.age = a;
            this.gender = gen;
        }
         
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "Name=" + this.name + "::Age=" + this.age + "::Gender=" + this.gender;
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Причем что можно поменять именно в коде? Т.к. делаю все с телефона (ide тоже мобильная).

Comment: Возможно, вы пытаетесь считать кирилицу.  Попробуйте это: `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in,"Cp866"); `

Comment: Может вам следовало сначала разархивировать zip-файл (см. [Разархивирование zip файла в android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613221/)), и прочитать из него `csv`-файл или файлы, а уже потом использовать `Scanner` для чтения текстовых данных?

Comment: Вроде как мне надо считать напрямую из архива, не распаковывая его. Зонтик, спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Что значит _считать напрямую из архива, не распаковывая его_??  Это возможно только, если csv-файл заархивирован как _ресурс_ вместе с вашим кодом в jar(!) файл, но тогда и читать его содержимое нужно через доступ к ресурсам.